# Variable from form to Javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to get variable from a form to add dates to current date. I get the number, but the outcome date is way off. If I hardcore the number it works fine and when I try to display the variable it gets right.

Why does it not display the right date?

```
 $("input[name='newDate']").on('ifClicked',function addDays(date,days) { 
     var today = new Date();
     var numberOfDaysToAdd = this.value; 
     today.setDate(today.getDate() + (numberOfDaysToAdd));
     alert(today +'value: ' + numberOfDaysToAdd);  
});
```

Comment: What is the use of function name addDays and arguments date,days? Are you using it anywhere inside the click handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try to get variable from a form to add dates to current date. I get the number, but the outcome date is way off

Use `parseInt();`. I think you are trying to add a string value to the date and it is messing up. Parsing it to integer might help.

`parseInt("12",10)` if your input value is 12.

So use the below code.

```
var today = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = parseInt(this.value,10); //parse to Integer
today.setDate(today.getDate() + (numberOfDaysToAdd));
alert(today + 'value: ' + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver :-)

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. You can mark my response as answer Only  if it helped you to resolve the issue.

Comment: *Always* use the second parameter to `parseInt(value, radix)`. If you don't and your `value` starts with a leading zero, it will be interpreted as octal.

Comment: @user3114969 you need to use the updated answer. the change is in the `parseInt`